# Why do pages appear to be loading on Tails before Tor is finished connecting?

Tags: tails

I am running Tails Version 0.22, and I have noticed that the Tails home page sometines loads before Tails. I am led to conclude this because the Tor icon is still yellow and it shows as still loading and the control panel shows the same when I check it. Why is this happening, how can I prevent it, and what kind of new vulnerabilties is it creating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The firewall is loaded early in Tails boot sequence. So no connections are possible without Tor. What you describe is only an artifact (a *race*) on how Tor and Vidalia reports their status.

Since [Tails 0.22.1](https://tails.boum.org/news/version_0.22.1/), Tails do no start the web browser automatically and only shows a notification.